# How can I filter the news feed by type=status, using the Graph API of Facebook's home?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

The Graph API of Facebook's home:

Request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=.....
```

JSON response:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"status",
         "id":"100003063094116_114168602028576",
         "created_time":"2011-11-07T16:28:44+0000"
      },
      {
         "type":"link",
         "id":"100003063094116_114172085361561",
         "created_time":"2011-11-07T16:27:44+0000"
      }
   ],
   "paging":{
      "previous":"https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=type&limit=2&access_token=....&since=1320683324",
      "next":"https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?fields=type&limit=2&access_token=....&until=1320683263"
   }
}
```

How can I can filter the news feed of `"type"="status"`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try FQL query instead:

```
SELECT status_id, time, source, message FROM status WHERE uid = me()
```

me() may be replaced by any other facebook user ID

[and may be tested here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/)

Comment: Hello rudolf ,How can i used the FQL ?

Comment: The request url is : https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT status_id, time, source, message FROM status where uid = me() , but the "https://graph.facebook.com/me/home" Corresponding FQL is ???

Comment: Could you specifify how exactly do you call request to https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=.....?